# Как изменить свойства кнопок в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

Пишу шаблонер (скрин прилагаю).

Кто-нибудь знает, как поместить в кнопку определённый текст?
(ЮЗЕР нажимает на *кнопку* и в `lineEdit` помещается этот текст)

**desing.py**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    
    # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
    #
    # Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
    #
    # WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
    
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(492, 260)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
            self.scrollArea.setEnabled(True)
            self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 121, 141))
            self.scrollArea.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(121, 141))
            self.scrollArea.setMouseTracking(False)
            self.scrollArea.setTabletTracking(False)
            self.scrollArea.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
            self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(False)
            self.scrollArea.setToolTip("")
            self.scrollArea.setToolTipDuration(-1)
            self.scrollArea.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
            self.scrollArea.setAutoFillBackground(False)
            self.scrollArea.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
            self.scrollArea.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
            self.scrollArea.setLineWidth(1)
            self.scrollArea.setMidLineWidth(7)
            self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
            self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.scrollArea.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
            self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
            self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 104, 244))
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
            self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
            self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_1.setStyleSheet("")
            self.button_1.setObjectName("button_1")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
            self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
            self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
            self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
            self.button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_5.setObjectName("button_5")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
            self.button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_6.setObjectName("button_6")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
            self.button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_7.setObjectName("button_7")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
            self.button_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.button_8.setObjectName("button_8")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
            self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 21, 201, 61))
            self.lineEdit.setText("")
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 110, 91, 23))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.button_copy = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.button_copy.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 110, 75, 23))
            self.button_copy.setObjectName("button_copy")
            self.butto_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.butto_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 140, 75, 23))
            self.butto_clear.setObjectName("butto_clear")
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            self.button_copy.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.copy)
            self.butto_clear.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)
            self.button_1.pressed.connect(self.lineEdit.paste)
            self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.lineEdit.selectAll)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.button_1.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
            self.button_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 1"))
            self.button_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 2"))
            self.button_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 3"))
            self.button_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 4"))
            self.button_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 5"))
            self.button_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 6"))
            self.button_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 7"))
            self.button_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 8"))
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скопируйте текст..."))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выделить ВСЁ"))
            self.button_copy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Копировать"))
            self.butto_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить"))
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
from design import *  # Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 1
        self.ui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_1)
        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 2
        self.ui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_2)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 1
    def MyFunction_1(self):
        a = "My Ok Button";

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 2
    def MyFunction_2(self):
        a = "My Ok Button";


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставить текст в QLineEdit:
`QLineEdit.setText(const QString &)`

**main_990858.py**

```
import sys

from design_990858 import Ui_MainWindow                          # design
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 1
        self.ui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_1)
        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 2
        self.ui.button_2.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_2)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 1
    def MyFunction_1(self):
        a = "My Ok Button1";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(a)                                    # <---

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 2
    def MyFunction_2(self):
        a = "My Ok Button2";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(a)                                    # <---



if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design_990858.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(492, 260)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setEnabled(True)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 121, 141))
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(121, 141))
        self.scrollArea.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.scrollArea.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.scrollArea.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.scrollArea.setToolTip("")
        self.scrollArea.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.scrollArea.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.scrollArea.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.scrollArea.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.scrollArea.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.scrollArea.setLineWidth(1)
        self.scrollArea.setMidLineWidth(7)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scrollArea.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 104, 244))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_1.setStyleSheet("")
        self.button_1.setObjectName("button_1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_5.setObjectName("button_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_6.setObjectName("button_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_7.setObjectName("button_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_8.setObjectName("button_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 21, 201, 61))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 110, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.button_copy = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_copy.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 110, 75, 23))
        self.button_copy.setObjectName("button_copy")
        self.butto_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.butto_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 140, 75, 23))
        self.butto_clear.setObjectName("butto_clear")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.button_copy.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.copy)
        self.butto_clear.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)

# ?       self.button_1.pressed.connect(self.lineEdit.paste)                    # ---

        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.lineEdit.selectAll)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button_1.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.button_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 1"))
        self.button_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 2"))
        self.button_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 3"))
        self.button_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 4"))
        self.button_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 5"))
        self.button_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 6"))
        self.button_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 7"))
        self.button_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 8"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скопируйте текст..."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выделить ВСЁ"))
        self.button_copy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Копировать"))
        self.butto_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ПОДСКЖИТЕ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА .... 

в данном коде текст накладывается на другой (т.е. нажав BUTTON_1, потом BUTTON_2   - в LINEEDIT осталось остался лишь текст с BUTTON_2).

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы текст присоединялся к уже написанному?

Comment: Замените `self.ui.lineEdit.setText(a) ` на `self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} + {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))`